# Crash in dlopen ( receiving SIGBUS )

Tags: c, linux, dbus, dlopen

One of my applications is crashing because of SIGBUS signal.
The following is the stack trace from the gdb. Basically, the dlopen call is failing. I am running CentOS 6.3 64 bit.

```
Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0x0000003cfc6175de in strcpy () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.9.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003cfc6175de in strcpy () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#1  0x0000003cfc6090b2 in _dl_load_cache_lookup () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#2  0x0000003cfc608612 in _dl_map_object () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#3  0x0000003cfc612b05 in dl_open_worker () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x0000003cfc60e266 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#5  0x0000003cfc6125aa in _dl_open () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x0000003cfca00f66 in dlopen_doit () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#7  0x0000003cfc60e266 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#8  0x0000003cfca0129c in _dlerror_run () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#9  0x0000003cfca00ee1 in dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#10 0x00000000004b4425 in my_open_dbus_func (f_name=0x558f2d "libdbus-glib-1.so.2")
```

I tried writing a simple program with these two lines which works just fine:

```
void * h = dlopen( "libdbus-glib-1.so.2", RTLD_LAZY );
dlclose( h );
```

I also tried running my original application under valgrind and it worked without any problem.

Any help/pointers are really appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us some more code? Can you provide a minimal, self-contained example?

Comment: Could you change your simple program to use `RTLD_NOW` instead of `RTLD_LAZY` and let us know if that works.  Also just curious what does `nm` report on the shared library

Comment: As it seems to code fails in `strcpy()` I dare to say this most likely dues to memory management corruption which happend (way) before the call in question (`dlopen()`).

Comment: I am trying but any stand-alone example I come up runs fine. It appears that my application as a whole is failing. It could be the case that I am doing something wrong before I reach to a "dlopen" point ( stack/heap corruption etc ). But then gdb or valgrind would have detected that case. Thinking...thinking....

Comment: You did reproduce the described behaviour under Valgrind? And during this very run Valgrind did not complain about anthing? If yes: I withdraw my comment.

Comment: @esm My simple program works fine with RTLD_LAZY or RTLD_NOW. It always worked. My main application is causing the problem. Any way, I just tried RTLD_NOW in my original application without any luck. Also, nm on libdbus did not give me any information ( no symbols )

Comment: @alk is there another way to figure out memory management issues? other than valgrind?

Comment: Do you have the possibility to switch to a different version of glibc. Probably testing with 2.11 or 2.13 on a different system?

Comment: How about doing what it tells you in the error?  Use debuginfo-install?

Comment: Out of the blue: Try running ldconfig (as root). And as you are at it you might like to check your `/etc/ld.so.conf` for any rubbish.

Comment: One code for `SIGBUS` is `BUS_ADRALN`, address alignment.  `strcpy()` is the function with the crash, perhaps copying the name.  The pointer, `f_name`, is not aligned to a 64 bit boundary, right?  Does that matter?

Comment: What is the output if you set the environment variable `LD_DEBUG=all`?

Comment: If `LD_DEBUG=all` is too much output, try `LD_DEBUG=libs`, help with `LD_DEBUG=help`. Interesting is the output of the last `trying file=`. On this string the `strcpy` is done.

Comment: It appears that one of the static library ( from third-party vedor ) was doing the shady memory management which somehow lead my dlopen call to crash. The code was written to delect the virtual environment. The problem could have been easily detected on valgrind but if application run under valgrind the third-party library would take a different code path ( considering that valgrind is physical machine )

Comment: @Icarus3 Perhaps writing and accepting an answer explaining the problem and the solution for the sake of future readers might be a good idea :)

Comment: Make sure your system is configured to generate core dumps. Looking at the core dump might give you some indications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that one of the static library ( from third-party vedor ) was doing the shady memory management which somehow lead my dlopen call to crash. The code was written to delect the virtual environment. The problem could have been easily detected on valgrind but if application run under valgrind the third-party library would take a different code path ( considering that valgrind is physical machine )

unfortunatly, I do not know what they fixed in their static library but it seems to work. I am writing this answer ( and accepting it ) to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check whether the `h` is not NULL after `dlopen`. I may assume the `dlclose` may crash with a NULL pointer given as a parameter.