# bus error at glibc when running python command

Tags: coredump, dlopen, bus-error

I encountered the problem when I run a `conan install` command.
[Conan](https://github.com/conan-io/conan) is a pure python project.
I try to use gdb to debug the core file, and the backtrace is like this:

```
#0  0x00007f3a7e3ee5d3 in strncmp () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strcmp.S:2075
#1  0x00007f3a7e3d2429 in print_statistics (rtld_total_timep=0x7ffea4463a90) at ../sysdeps/generic/_itoa.h:67
#2 ...
```

[the gdb layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnu5y.png)

[Download the core file](https://fastupload.io/KNI7Xw78Oquc4Bj/file)

The state of the cpu is strange. rip points to 0x7f3a7e3ee5d3 <strncmp+5779>，which seems not to be a valid instruction entry.

I also debug the command directly, and the backtrace is like this:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7ff25d3 in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#1  0x00007ffff7fd6429 in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#2  0x00007ffff7fd961b in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#3  0x00007ffff7fde515 in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x00007ffff7daf928 in _dl_catch_exception () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7fde963 in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x00007ffff7fe4db0 in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#7  0x00007ffff7daf928 in _dl_catch_exception () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#8  0x00007ffff7fe460a in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#9  0x00007ffff7f9634c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
#10 0x00007ffff7daf928 in _dl_catch_exception () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#11 0x00007ffff7daf9f3 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#12 0x00007ffff7f96b59 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
#13 0x00007ffff7f963da in dlopen () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
#14 0x00000000005cebc6 in _PyImport_FindSharedFuncptr (prefix=0x6234a4 "PyInit", shortname=0x7ffff5f359a0 "_sqlite3", 
    pathname=0x7ffff5f66720 "/path/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so", fp=0x0)
    at /usr/local/src/conda/python-3.10.9/Python/dynload_shlib.c:100
```

I fixed this problem by reinstall the python environment in miniconda.

[similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544567/crash-in-dlopen-receiving-sigbus)

Is this a bug from glibc/python, or just the _sqlite3.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so is broken?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544567/crash-in-dlopen-receiving-sigbus

Comment: It's not a bug in `strncmp` itself; glibc's implementation doesn't do computed jumps that could jump into the middle of an instruction with bad inputs.  It does use an indirect jump on the relative misalignment of the two pointers, but it uses labels not hard-coded sizes.  (Surprising that it's using a non-AVX version; is this on an old or low-power CPU, or a misconfigured VM?  Or perhaps a wild jump just happened to end up in the middle of that function instead of some other.  Does `print_statistics` normally call `strncmp`?)

Comment: The fault address is in the SSE2, SSSE3, or SSE4 version built from this source:
 https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/strcmp.S.html#2055 - the `LABEL(ashr_15):` misalignment case with `pslldq $1, %xmm2`.  The indirect jump is https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/strcmp.S.html#221

Comment: Oh right, `ld.so` uses the baseline SSE2 versions of the glibc funcs it needs, that's why it's using the non-SSE4.2 version.  (The SSE4.2 version uses `pcmpistri` for while getting started, but has some similar code.  But the instructions surrounding a `pslldq $1, %xmm2` are ordered differently, so it's not that.)  Also this explains why it's just called `strncmp`, not `__strncmp_ssse3` or whatever like normal where a dynamic-link-time resolver function sets the GOT function pointer to be the best version for this CPU.